# In Faro how do players indicate/remember their call of the last three cards ("Calling the Turn")

Tags: house-rules

I've been trying to learn how to deal Faro. Online sources such as Wikipedia and Wizard of Odds mention that when three cards remain players can 'call the turn' stating the order they think the final three cards will be turned up. I cannot find any mention though of how the players' call(s) should be indicated; there doesn't seem to be any place to show it on a standard Faro layout, and pen and paper seems clumsy even in a casual home game. At the same time, with a number of people wanting to call the turn and the dealer and players needing some aid to remember, I'd be interested if anyone knows the 'real' way, or has a suggested way to track this. It doesn't seem like any casino at any time would allow this to be done simply verbally, so it strikes me there must be a way to handle it concretely.